# Expose Laravel Tasks Programmatically and 're-usable' for different purposes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to define some 'things-to-do/run'  (aka maybe Commands?) in a Task Schedule.
So i may have a Command pretend called PushNotificationJob and another Command called WriteToLogFileJob, etc.
I want to exposed these in my admin GUI so that I can add a BatchProcess.
So imagine a button in a Laravel CMS page that says 'Add Batch Process', and in that page collects info for a new Batch Process:

1. what Task/job to run (dropdown that has pretend currently defined
   Tasks: PushNotificationJob and WriteToLogFileJob)
2. when to run it (cron string)
3. key/value params to send to that Task/job.

Now pretend I defined a BatchProcess on that page called 'Send App Update Notif to Users' that uses the PushNotificationJob task (which send params: --message='Hey $name, update your app!' and --priority='high' that should run daily).
and another BatchProcess called 'Send newsletter to users' that also uses the same PushNotificationJob task if possible (which send params: --message='Hey $name, sign into our app to checkout the latest Newsletter!' and --priority='normal') which runs bi-weekly. Really the params and time are the only things different, the Task itself is still the same which sends a push notification with that message param with that priority to a user.

Is this all doable?
I've seen some ways to expose all the Current Tasks to the UI.
and maybe also seen a way you can set a cron string for a Task... but this seems like it reuses the same Task so it cannot make 'multiple jobs that re-use the same task' in different ways via different cron strings/params.

Here is the most info I got so far to maybe expose the Tasks to the UI:

[laravel add scheduler dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801334/laravel-add-scheduler-dynamically)

[LARAVEL: Get an array of scheduled tasks for output in admin dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559769/laravel-get-an-array-of-scheduled-tasks-for-output-in-admin-dashboard)

If this is achievable, let me know below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a way to do this based on the other posts:
https://github.com/armyofda12mnkeys/laravel-task-gui-linkage (master branch)
So first create some commands... The options/args for those commands should be pre-defined in your Command class (which kinda limits how many and which exact args dynamically you can send via your GUI).

Then in your GUI, type the name of the task (or link that form value to a dropdown list, via DB or hardcoded) and set a timing (cron or keyword like hourly) and params to send to it.

Then the Kernel.php can dynamically register them based on other code I saw.