# Is there a way to get the scheduled task as an array from a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scheduler

I would like to get the scheduled tasks list from a controller. [Some packages](https://github.com/hmazter/laravel-schedule-list), [articles](http://laravelcoding.com/blog/adding-a-schedulelist-command) and even [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559769/laravel-get-an-array-of-scheduled-tasks-for-output-in-admin-dashboard) explain how to display it from a command, but I did not found how to do it without a command. My goal is to get an array of scheduled task with their date and description.

Is there a way to get the scheduled task as an array (or an object list, or anything that can be easily handled) from a controller?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559769/laravel-get-an-array-of-scheduled-tasks-for-output-in-admin-dashboard

Comment: I think the answer here has use, as it does some parsing of the returned events, but the question you linked to already had a 2016 answer showing how to do it in a controller. It was not a well-written answer (I've cleaned it up) but it presented a very similar solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to get all scheduled tasks:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Cron\CronExpression;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
$schedule = app()->make(\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule::class);

$events = collect($schedule->events())->map(function($event) {
    $cron = CronExpression::factory($event->expression);
    $date = Carbon::now();
    if ($event->timezone) {
        $date->setTimezone($event->timezone);
    }

    return (object) [
        'expression'  => $event->expression,
        'command'     => Str::after($event->command, '\'artisan\' '),
        'next_run_at' => $cron->getNextRunDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
});
```

You have a collection of objects (in `$events`) with three properties:

- **expression** - example: `12 1 * * *`
- **command** - example: `mypackage:mycommand`
- **next_run_at** - example: `2018-01-10 16:50:49`

Comment: I tried this solution, but showing error: {message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\CronExpression' not found",…}...

Comment: @AnoopSankar assuming you enter this in tinker, you can either type `use \Cron\CronExpression;` or use the full namespace instead of the class. 
You will need `use \Carbon\Carbon;` as well and for people working with Larvael versions lower than 5.4, the str_after helper is unavailable and you will have to define it yourself: `function str_after($subject,$search) { return $search === '' ? $subject : array_reverse(explode($search, $subject, 2))[0]; }`

Comment: That is useful. Just one question, if I add a job with some parameters to the schedule, I haven't found a way to retrieve the parameters value with this approach. Example: `$schedule->job(new CommandJob($value->command, $value->is_curl))->cron($value->schedule);` I would like to get the 2 parameters i passed to the job otherwise in the list I have 5 CommandJob but I don't know what they're making