# How to get scheduled commands as array from the controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am wondering how can I get scheduled commands as an array from a controller?

I’ve googled for that and found similar questions on StackOverflow. They(answers) are not working anymore. We need a new code that will be able to get those data. Thanks in advance.

> The anwsers given in
>
> [LARAVEL: Get an array of scheduled tasks for output in admin dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559769/laravel-get-an-array-of-scheduled-tasks-for-output-in-admin-dashboard)
>
> [Is there a way to get the scheduled task as an array from a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190007/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-scheduled-task-as-an-array-from-a-controller)
>
> are of no use

P.S. Don't mark this as duplicate, I said clearly that I've seen other questions and we need to find out a new solution.

Comment: What questions did you find that where not good? it might help so we don't look in the same direction. Can you link the questions you deemed not useful.

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559769/laravel-get-an-array-of-scheduled-tasks-for-output-in-admin-dashboard 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559769/laravel-get-an-array-of-scheduled-tasks-for-output-in-admin-dashboard

Comment: what about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190007/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-scheduled-task-as-an-array-from-a-controller/48191912#48191912 ?

Comment: I’ve just tested it. Not working too.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are testing this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the scheduled task as an array from a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190007/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-scheduled-task-as-an-array-from-a-controller)

Comment: All the codes are in the related answers that are not working.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you show some code ? For example the way you tested the solution provided in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190007/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-scheduled-task-as-an-array-from-a-controller maybe the answer is still correct but the implementation is not right